# Noob question x 2: toroidal channel & toroidal insert

Tags: modeling

Hello (blender) world...

Please go easy on me on this first post. I'm new to Blender (and 3D in general, but otherwise software literate) and ready for Total Immersion in all the usual tutorial channels etc. But it would be great if someone could start me off on the right foot for what I need to achieve...

I'm trying to model a circular concrete channel, roughly square section. Inside sits a metal ring, again square section but with a band around the inner surface, of a different material. A bit like an o-ring in a square ring, all inside a square channel, everything concentric...

I'm happy to put in the learning for materials etc but... but... what's the best way to make the square torus (with additional band), and the square toroidal channel?

Obvs I have read about cut lines to reshape the torus but should I use extrude instead? I had a go with that but the extrusion had only vertices, no faces... similarly starting off with a U-shaped plane then using rotate.

So, if an expert could tell me which learning path to follow, I'd be eternally grateful. Eternity being what it will take otherwise...
[image: Sketch of object(s)]

Comment: Please post some reference images.